# display selected column value in filter in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am able to get the selected value in filter from checkValues : function(a, b, c, d). here d contains the selected value. I want to display this selected value in the data grid. is there any way or feature provided by JQGrid?

Comment: What do you mean selected value? Is this the value some text you selected inside jqGrid cell? or is that a row?